# My Cloth Sim with Pressure is Acting very Unusually

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

So I've been making this scene with some balloons. They have been absolutely fine until now. The sim plays through absolutely fine (sort of) and then the 2nd time around, even if I bake the sim, it starts going all crazy and i have no idea why. I think it's a bug. I've made the scene exactly the same before, it had self collision and collision with other objects and they were all interacting fine. Then all of a sudden the animation wasn't playing back and kept crashing blender. So I remade this scene and now this is happening.

Here's a link to the blend file [image]

And Here's a link to a video of the problem: https://vimeo.com/549503971/9e965b00bd

Here's a link to another video with exactly the same setup and it's working fine: https://vimeo.com/549505660

Hope someone can help because it's driving me nuts. Remade this project a few times and goes fine for a while then starts going nuts for some reason.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Arta, you should use https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload your blend files. and IF you provide a link to your google drive - you should NOT let us ask for permission ....you want help, right!? so make it easy for us!

Comment: @Chris thank you, I've just replaced the file. Apologies, never done this before! Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

i got a "good result" by changing this:

1. change back gravity on "F" to 1 and applied scale for your cloth object

[image]

2. change gravity speed z on world settings to 10

[image]

3. changed pressure to .1

[image]

4. then i tapped delete all bakes, and bake

got this:

[image]